# Apache Tomcat can't create log file and fails

Tags: windows, logging, tomcat, maven

I try to start Apache Maven at Win7 x64 SP1.

```
java version "1.7.0_09"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_09-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.5-b02, mixed mode)
```

Apache Tomcat 6.0.36 x64 (also tried to use 7 version and x86 versions, no matter).

It fails immediately after start with an error:

```
java.util.logging.ErrorManager: 4
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Programs\apache-tomcat-6.0.36" -Dcatalina.home=C:\Programs\apache-tomcat-6.0.36"\logs\catalina.2012-11-30.log
```

No log file created at `\apache-tomcat-6.0.36\logs`

I tried completely disable Windows firewall and UAC. It doesn't helps.

It seems like problem at the filename with quote:

```
C:\Programs\apache-tomcat-6.0.36"\logs\catalina.2012-11-30.log
```

Any suggestions how to solve this issue?

**UPDATE**: SET command results added

```
C:\Users\Dana>set
ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
APPDATA=C:\Users\Dana\AppData\Roaming
CATALINA_HOME=C:\Programs\apache-tomcat-6.0.36\
CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program Files\Common Files
CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
CommonProgramW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files
COMPUTERNAME=DANA-PC
ComSpec=C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
FP_NO_HOST_CHECK=NO
HOMEDRIVE=C:
HOMEPATH=\Users\Dana
JAVA_HOME=C:\Programs\Java\jdk1.7.0
LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\Dana\AppData\Local
LOGONSERVER=\\DANA-PC
M3_HOME=C:\Programs\apache-maven-3\
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=2
OS=Windows_NT
Path=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32
\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Programs\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\;C:\Program Files\Microso
ft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web
Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\
;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Programs\apache-maven-
3\\bin\;
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=AMD64 Family 17 Model 3 Stepping 1, AuthenticAMD
PROCESSOR_LEVEL=17
PROCESSOR_REVISION=0301
ProgramData=C:\ProgramData
ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files
ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
ProgramW6432=C:\Program Files
PROMPT=$P$G
PSModulePath=C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\
PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public
SESSIONNAME=Console
SystemDrive=C:
SystemRoot=C:\Windows
TEMP=C:\Users\Dana\AppData\Local\Temp
TMP=C:\Users\Dana\AppData\Local\Temp
USERDOMAIN=Dana-PC
USERNAME=Dana
USERPROFILE=C:\Users\Dana
VS110COMNTOOLS=C:\Programs\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\
windir=C:\Windows
windows_tracing_flags=3
windows_tracing_logfile=C:\BVTBin\Tests\installpackage\csilogfile.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the **Environment Variables** dialog ([XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310519) / [Win7](http://www.itechtalk.com/thread3595.html)) and look for **CATALINA_HOME** under both the **User** and **System** variables sections. If it has a superfluous quote tacked on at the end, delete it, OK your way out and retry Tomcat.

Comment: I checked it already. There is no any quotes.

Comment: Sure? Can you [paste](http://pastebin.com) the result of `set`? Also, you didn't by any chance edit any of the batch files in Tomcat's bin directory, did you?

Comment: OK, I added `set` results to my question. Moreover, if I remove CATALINA_HOME from Environment Variables nothing changes. And I didn't touch any batch files. It is fresh zip instance from official site.

Comment: Can you remove the backslash at the end of CATALINA_HOME, and also fix the double backslash in the PATH to Maven's bin dir?

Comment: OK, I did it and now Tomcat falls more quickly: no logs, no stacktrase.

Comment: Weird. Can you scrub it all (environment variables, files, everything), then re-download the latest 32 or 64-bit ZIP distro, unpack to something like C:\Programs\Tomcat and see if the startup batch file works? If not, how about the service installer versions?

Comment: I still don't know what that was but after a lot of tries Tomcat starts! And now it looks completely stable. Nothing changed from last time. I confused.

Answer (score 0):

For everyone looking for a solution:

Remove the backslash at the end of

```
CATALINA_HOME=C:\Programs\apache-tomcat-6.0.36\
```

**to**

```
CATALINA_HOME=C:\Programs\apache-tomcat-6.0.36
```

Worked for me